# A country/folk song with a special manner of singing I have trouble to describe. How is Can't Stare Down A Montaineer from The Crooked Jades singular?

Tags: genre, folk, country

I haven't a lot of culture about the manners of singing available across the U.S.A.

I enjoyed [Can't Stare Down A Mountaineer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tpYtYbX0TfI) from *The Crooked Jades*.

It's a country/folk song, but the way of singing it was for me, at the same time, both uncommon and familiar: as if it was a technique coming from the past. A citation, an homage of a ancient manner of singing.

Therefore, I'm not able to describe what I'm hearing. This song is elaborated, seems being following some rules, but I can't tell more.

What is it song an example of? How does it find its place in the country or contry/folk sub genres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of what's called the "Roots Americana" genre, characterized by acoustic instruments, and performances that take modern inspiration from early and mid-twentieth century country, folk, blues and bluegrass styles. You can hear other Americana tracks on the popular *O Brother Where Art Thou* soundtrack.

For an example of the original songs that inspired the genre, here's an example of a classic Carter Family song (country):

Here's a Mississippi John Hurt blues:

Here's a Bill Monroe bluegrass number: